# Index notation with non-commuting matrix entries

Tags: matrices, tensors

Just a contradiction I came across working with matrix multiplication in index notation: I'm probably using some rule wrong, but I can't figure out which one.

Consider the expression $A_{ij} B_{ik}$, where A and B are matrices. We can rewrite this in the following two ways, assuming the entries of A and B commute:

$$A_{ij} B_{ik} = A^T_{ji} B_{ik} = (A^T B)_{jk}$$
$$A_{ij} B_{ik} = A_{ij} B^T_{ki} = B^T_{ki} A_{ij} = (B^T A)_{kj}$$

These are equivalent since:

$$(A^T B)_{jk} = (A^T B)^T_{kj} = (B^T A)_{kj}$$

However, if the entries of A and B don't commute, then the step $A_{ij} B^T_{ki} = B^T_{ki} A_{ij}$ in our second expression is invalid, and instead we find:

$$A_{ij} B_{ik} = (B^T A)_{kj} +\text{some non-commuting part}$$

Now I believe $(A^T B)_{jk} = (B^T A)_{kj}$ is still true in this case, so we can write:

$$A_{ij} B_{ik} = (A^T B)_{jk} = (B^T A)_{kj} \neq A_{ij} B_{ik}$$

Which is a contradiction. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by entries commuting?  In a particular basis, $A_{ij}$ and $B^T_{ki}$ are plain numbers.  How the operators are composed--how the matrices are multiplied--is dictated merely by the placement of the indices, not which of $A$ or $B$ is written on the left or right.

Comment: For example, A and B could be matrices of Grassmann numbers, vectors, or matrices themselves. In such a case we cannot simply say that $A_{ij} B^T_{ki} = B^T_{ki} A_{ij}$, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use both subscripts and superscripts for the indices of my matrices.  It's harder to forget how matrix multiplication works that way (at least to me).

So given the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 9 & 8 & 7\end{bmatrix}$, the element of $A$ in the $i$th row and $j$th column can be written $A^i_j$.  For instance $A^2_1 = 4$ and $A^1_2 = 2$.  So as you can see, objects of the form $A^i_j$ are just *numbers*, not matrices.

How does matrix multiplication work then?  It is just $$[AB]^i_j = \sum_k A^i_kB^k_j$$
You can see that the element in the $i$th row and $j$th column of the resultant matrix ($AB$) is given by the sum of the elements in the $i$th row of $A$ multiplied by the $j$th row of $B$.

A note on the notation: $A$ is the matrix, $A^i_j = [A]^i_j$ is the element of the matrix $A$ in the $i$th row and $j$th column, and $[A^i_j]$ is the matrix with all elements $A^i_j$, $i \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, $j \in \{1, 2, \dots, m\}$ (so in this case $A = [A^i_j]$).

We can see then that the transpose of a matrix in index notation is simply a reversal of the indices: $$[A^i_j]^T = [A^j_i]$$

Let's look at your statement: $(A^T B)_{jk} = (A^T B)^T_{kj} = (B^T A)_{kj}$.

Using my notation here (I didn't really invent it), we'd write this as $[A^TB]^j_k = [(A^TB)^T]^k_j = [B^TA]^k_j$.

Here's how we'd prove it:

$$[A^TB]^j_k = \sum_i [A^T]^j_iB^i_k = \sum_i A^i_j B^i_k = \sum_i A^i_j [B^T]^k_i = \sum_i [B^T]^k_i A^i_j$$

I'm going to stop here a second to note that I can commute $A^i_j$ and $[B^T]^k_i$ because these are just *numbers*, not matrices.  I also want to note that we had to commute those two because matrix multiplication is defined as $[MN]^a_b = M^a_cN^c_b$ and not $[MN]^a_b\ne M^c_bN^a_c$.  Continuing

$$\sum_i [B^T]^k_i A^i_j = [B^TA]^k_j$$

so the first and last parts are equal.  That the middle part is also equal to both sides is shown by $[(A^TB)^T]^k_j = [A^TB]^j_k = \sum_i [A^T]^j_iB^i_k = [A^TB]^j_k$ and $=[B^TA]^k_j$ from the above. $\ \ \square$

Comment: I dunno, I prefer to keep indices not lined up over the same slot, e.g. ${A^i}_j = {(A^T)_j}^i$.

Comment: I completely agree in the case of $A^i_j$ and $B^i_k$ just being numbers, as you said. My problem arises only in the case where this isn't true, such as when A and B are matrices of Grassmann variables, or when we've defined the indices to indicate submatrices, or any other non-commuting tensor.

Comment: @Timsey OK.  In that case, there's no contradiction because $(A^T B)_{jk} \ne (B^T A)_{kj}$, in general, whenever the entries of your matrix don't commute.  That is, $(AB)^T \ne B^TA^T$ which you seem to be assuming still works in this case.

Comment: Ah alright! I wasn't aware of that, thank you. Does there exist a general expression for $[(A^T B)_{jk}]^T$ in the form $(...)_{kj}$ in that case?

Comment: This essentially comes down to "Is there an analog of the expression $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$ when the elements of the matrices $A$ and $B$ are noncommutative?"  The answer is that I don't know of a simple expression, but if you just want an entrywise expression then look at the line under "Here's how we'd prove it" above and stop before the commutation.  That is, the expression is $[A^TB]^j_k = \sum_i A^i_j [B^T]^k_i$.  Looking at this we can see that it's ALMOST $[B^TA]^k_j$, but the order of the factors in each term is reversed.

Comment: You're right. It would depend on the exact commutation relation, but this has given me some insight. Thank you!